# Dynamically create PowerShell scriptblock from scriptblock

Tags: function, powershell

I want to write a powershell function that returns a scriptblock by creating one dynamically based on a scriptblock passed in as an input parameter. I don't seem to be having much luck.

It's easy to write a method to invoke the scriptblock twice.

```
$x = { write-host "Hello" }
function DoIt([scriptblock] $s) { $s.Invoke(); }
function DoItTwice([scriptblock] $s) { $s.Invoke(); $s.Invoke(); }

DoIt($x)
DoItTwice($x)
```

It's harder to write a method that returns a scriptblock that has the effect of invoking the (input) scriptblock twice. The following doesn't work

```
function TwiceAsScriptBlock([scriptblock] $s)
{
    function twice
    {
        $s.Invoke();
        $s.Invoke();
    }
    return { twice }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do the trick for you:

```
function TwiceAsScriptBlock([scriptblock] $s)
{

    $ScriptBlock = [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create("$s ; $s")
    Return $ScriptBlock 
}
```

[image: Powershell Return Scriptblock]

Comment: I tried variants along these lines. If I call Invoke() on the scriptblock returned, I get the following error: 
`TwiceAsScriptBlock : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 's'.`

Comment: It worked for me, I'll put a screenshot.
What version of powersehll are you running?

Comment: check the updated answer, As you can see when I Invoke the new scriptblock it output the message twice.

Comment: Ok - think I've been staring at this too long. I was trying `TwiceAsNewScriptBlock($x).Invoke()` - which is why I thought it didn't work. Thanks!